# Decode strings with special characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

When I was fetching some data through API, I have some Danish strings which came encoded like below:

| Encoded | Original |
| --- | --- |
| `Sk&#230;fte` | Skæfte |
| `s&#248;lv` | sølv |

Tried combinations of `decodeURIComponent()` and `escape()` but that doesn't help. Any ways to decode the string in native JS irrespective of the encoded language (Danish, in this case)?

Comment: Those are html-entities, you can use the example in that other question to decode it.